# Communication between threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

Got a programm with 2 threads. one thread is writing some stuff into the console.

```
public class Konsole extends Thread {

    static int id = 0;

    Client client;

    public Konsole(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("========= Konsole "+ ++id +" started");

    while(true) {


        try {

            String line = client.fromServer.readLine();

            client.commands.add(line);
                System.out.println(line);

                if(line == null) {break;}


        } catch (IOException e) {}

    }
```

in the Client class exits a public static stack.
But the stack is allways empty, the Konsole isn't able to access the stack.
Can someone give me a hint why?

Client class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Client extends Thread {

    // Verbindungsvariablen
    final String user = "user";
    final String pass = "pass";
    public String host = "localhost";
    int port = 21;


    // PASV
    int portNew;
    String ipNew = "";

    public static Stack<String> commands = new Stack<String>();

    boolean lastCommand = false;

    // Sockets
    Socket serverSocket;
    Socket pasvSocket;
    PrintWriter writeCommands;
    BufferedReader fromServer;

    PrintWriter writePasvCommands;
    BufferedReader fromPasvServer;

    // Baut die Verbindung auf
    public void connect() throws IOException {

        try {
            serverSocket = new Socket(host, port);
            System.out.println("Baue Verbindung auf ...");
            fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    serverSocket.getInputStream()));
            writeCommands = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream(),
                    true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Host unbekannt!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void USER() throws IOException {
        writeCommands.print("USER " + user + "\n");
        writeCommands.flush();
    }

    public void PASS() {
        writeCommands.print("PASS " + pass +"\n");
        writeCommands.flush();
    }

    public void NOOP() {
        writeCommands.print("NOOP\n");
        writeCommands.flush();
    }

    public void getStatus() {
        Thread konsole = new Thread(new Konsole(this));
        konsole.start();
    }

    // PASV anschalten
    public void PASV() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        writeCommands.print("PASV\n");
        writeCommands.flush();
        //getPasvCon();


    }
public void getPasvCon() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!");
        // Commands abholen


        // IP Adresse holen

        String pasv = commands.lastElement();
        String ipAndPort = pasv.substring(pasv.indexOf("(") + 1,
                pasv.indexOf(")"));

        StringTokenizer getIp = new StringTokenizer(ipAndPort);

        // holt die IP
        String ipNew = "";   // IP für den neuen Socket
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i < 3) {
                ipNew += (getIp.nextToken(",") + ".");
            } else {
                ipNew += (getIp.nextToken(","));

            }
        }


        Integer portTemp1 = new Integer( getIp.nextToken(","));
        Integer portTemp2 = new Integer (getIp.nextToken(","));
        portNew = (portTemp1 << 8 )+ portTemp2;


        try {

            pasvSocket = new Socket(ipNew, portNew);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Host unbekannt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            fromPasvServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    pasvSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writePasvCommands = new PrintWriter(pasvSocket.getOutputStream(),
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   




    }

    public void LIST() throws IOException  {
    writeCommands.print("LIST\n");
    writeCommands.flush();

    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            connect();

    //      getStatus();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            USER();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PASS();


        try {
            PASV();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Client() throws IOException {

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Client test = new Client();
        Thread client = new Thread(test);
        client.start();

        Thread.sleep(300);


        Thread konsole = new Thread(new Konsole(test));
        konsole.start();



        Disrupter disrupt = new Disrupter(test);
        disrupt.start();



    }



}
```

(static is senseless, isn't it?)

Comment: Can you provide the Client class code?

Comment: You'd better use a synchronized collection.

Comment: added a thread.sleep and now it works.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: Stack extends Vector, so he's using a synchronized collection.

Comment: I'd try using wait and notify instead of sleep, you have less busy-waiting that way.

Comment: U sure client extend thread? Not like a good design...

Comment: ABLX: can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using `Thread.sleep()`.